# How can I compute this integral? (Without assuming that $m=1$)

Tags: integration

How can I compute this integral?

$\int_{0}^{1} \sin^{2}(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\mathrm dx$

Comment: Consider that $$\int_{0}^{1}\cos(2\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\,dx $$ differs from zero in very few cases, if $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Convert to complex exponential form is one way.

Comment: Is "missing context or details" really a good reason to close this question?

Answer (score 1):

hint : first use $\sin^2 a=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2a)$ 
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \sin^{2}(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\ dx&=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (1-\cos(\pi x))\sin(m\pi x)\ dx\\&=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (\sin(m\pi x)-\cos(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x))\ dx
\end{align}$$

then use product to sum formula

$$
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \sin(m\pi x)\ dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\cos(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \sin(m\pi x)\ dx-\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(\sin(m\pi x+\pi x)+\sin(m\pi x-\pi x))\ dx\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sin^2(X)=\frac{1-\cos(2X)}{2}$$

$2\cos(a)\sin(b)=$

$\sin(b+a)+\sin(b-a)$.